# Facebook Send To Messenger plugin doesn't redirect in-app browser

Tags: javascript, facebook, messenger

Using Facebook's mobile in-app browser to interact with a Send-To-Messenger plugin presents you a confirmation popup. However, as the in-app browser doesn't seem to support popups it simply treats it as a different page. Once you've confirmed it, you are presented with a white screen with a "1" in it, and the following URL is loaded:

`https://m.facebook.com/plugins/close_popup.php?reload=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fplugins%2Fsend_to_messenger.php%3Fapp_id%3D1764165680262750%26channel%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fstaticxx.facebook.com%252Fconnect%252Fxd_arbiter%252Fr%252FZ2duorNoYeF.js%253Fversion%253D42%2523cb%253Df3e4279a0da1f88%2526domain%253Dask-anything.me%2526origin%253Dhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fask-anything.me%25252Ff25432757602a5c%2526relation%253Dparent.parent%26color%3Dblue%26container_width%3D0%26locale%3Den_US%26messenger_app_id%3D1764165680262750%26page_id%3D858456220977544%26ref%3DxngEKWwvl%26sdk%3Djoey%26size%3Dxlarge%26ret%3Doptin%26act%3Dsend%26hash%3DAQAhWlE7tO0TnuS8#_=_`

The Messenger callback is triggered at this point but the user is left with a confusing white screen. Please see the following screenshots

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The same issue is already reported as a bug

https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/734961380786479/

Comment: We are facing similar issues, javascript redirection is not working in facebook's InApp browser.
https://stackoverflow.com/q/68101925/644949